# Extend login period for Admins

Tags: ee2, login

Is there a way to extend the login period for admins? Usually booted out withihn about 30mins of inactivity. I have a client who's wanting it to be much longer if possible...

A usergroup setting I've missed perhaps?

Running EE 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [Hidden Configuration Variables](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/general/hidden_configuration_variables.html#cp-session-ttl) page in the User Guide. You can adjust the `$config['cp-session-ttl'] = xx;` variable to extend the admin session length.